# Do airport agents accept firstname and lastname in wrong order?

Tags: tickets, bookings, suriname

I booked a flight from HCM City to Manchester on 25/09/2015, using Etihad Airways.
The input the last name as first name in wrong order.
My first name: Hoang, last name: Pham, but while booking, I enter my first name as Pham and last name as: Hoang.

Will the airport agents accept the wrong order of first name and last name, or I have to issue a name change to the airways?

Comment: since you have lots of time isn't it better to first try to see how much it costs to change the name on the ticket? I don't know if you can do it through "Manage your booking" or if you have to phone in at their office (and if fees apply).

Comment: It is also possible that you will be able to get it done for free, if you convince them that you are not transferring the ticket; just fixing the name.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a problem

when you check in airport the staff will correct it

Or you can contract their local centre/global contract centre.

Comment: Do you have a source / reference for this?

Comment: from my own experience, america airlines, delta, copa airline doesn't have problem with that