# First name and middle name printed the wrong way around on ticket!

Tags: australia, vietnam

I am travelling to Vietnam and Australia through Vietnam Airlines.

My passport name is:
Mrs A B C

The ticket has been printed as:
Mrs B A C

(To be clear; A to represent first name, B to represent middle name and C to represent last name)

There are no discrepancies in the spelling of any of the names. After reading an overwhelming amount of information and posts on forums, it seems as though it isn't an issue in general. It's just worrying to know I could be denied at the airport or even worse denied on flights abroad. My tickets cannot be reprinted by the travel agency. I can either cancel and rebook (at a VERY large price, £1200+) or take a chance... any further advice?

Comment: Are you Vietnamese? Or Korean, Chinese, Japanese... where surname comes first? In that case A should be last name (surname), not first, and C should be first name (given name). The order isn't important as long as it all the printed syllables are available on the passport.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/50983/13777 http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/24725/13777